# Migrating body text from 7 to 8, markup displays until edited and saved

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm migrating nodes and have run into a problem with the text formats when mapping our old site's input formats to the new site's input formats. (We're simplifying!)

Relevant yaml:

```
  body:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: body
    process:
      value: value
      format:
        plugin: static_map
        bypass: true
        source: body_format
        map:
          'plain_text': basic_html
          'basic_tags': basic_html
          'minimal_formatting': basic_html
          'filtered_html': basic_html
          'extended_tags': full_html
          'full_html': full_html
```

When I run this, all the content and formats are imported correctly, but the nodes all display the markup on the page until each node is edited and saved.

What could be causing this and how might I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2):

```
source: body_format
```

should have been

```
source: format
```

Turning off "bypass: true" let me see that it was just dumping them in with NO input set, opening and saving changed it to the default for that field.